# How to fill true values of a dataframe with column names?

Tags: python, pandas, mask

I have a DataFrame with True and False values.

```
       A      B      C      D
0  False  True   True   False
1  False  False  True   False
2  True   True   False  False
```

I want to fill the true values with column names and false values with 0. How can I do that?

i.e To get the result as

```
   A  B  C  D
0  0  B  C  0
1  0  0  C  0
2  A  B  0  0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First replace `booelan` to `int` and then use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) or [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with inverting mask by `~`:

```
df = df.astype(int).mask(df, df.columns.to_series(), axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  0  B  C  0
1  0  0  C  0
2  A  B  0  0
```

---

```
df = df.astype(int).where(~df, df.columns.to_series(), axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  0  B  C  0
1  0  0  C  0
2  A  B  0  0
```

Thank you [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45937336/how-to-fill-true-values-of-a-dataframe-with-column-names/45937375#comment78832493_45937375) for improvement in new versions of pandas `0.21.x`:

```
df = df.astype(int).mask(df, df.columns, axis=1)
```

`numpy` solution:

```
a = np.tile(df.columns, [len(df.index),1])
print (a)
[['A' 'B' 'C' 'D']
 ['A' 'B' 'C' 'D']
 ['A' 'B' 'C' 'D']]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.astype(int), a, 0), columns=df.columns, index = df.index)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  0  B  C  0
1  0  0  C  0
2  A  B  0  0
```

Comment: `df.astype(int).mask(df, df.columns, axis=1)` should do I guess?

Comment: it return for me `ValueError: other must be the same shape as self when an ndarray`

Comment: Also, `df.astype(int).where(~df, df.columns.to_series(), axis=1)` would work too.

Comment: I use `0.20.3`, python 3.5,  windows 7

Answer (score 0):

pandas 1.5.2

```
df = df.mask(df.astype(bool), df.columns.to_series(), axis=1)
```

---

not `astype(int)` but `astype(bool) or astype('bool')`

Otherwise **ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not uint8**

---

can't remove `.to_series()`

Otherwise **ValueError: other must be the same shape as self when an ndarray**